# GraphQL Playground without CDN in Apollo Server 2

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm migrating from Apollo Server Hapi v1 to Apollo Server Hapi v2. Our production environment does not have access to the Internet, so we were not able to host the built-in Graphiql client, and instead had to create our own Graphiql UI. I can reuse the Graphiql code that was developed for v1, but would prefer to use Apollo Server's built in Graphql Playground.

How can we use the new Graphql Playground without requiring the use of the CDN files index.css and middleware.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apollo server 2 uses under the hood [graphql-playground-middleware-express](https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-playground/tree/master/packages/graphql-playground-middleware-express) you can actually pass some options to it, but unfortunately no option that relates to cdn usability is available 
but there are some other solutions you can do:

1. **Quick and easy**
    I found out that when using the electron release of graphql-playground 
    it does not go to the internet and everything is locally running.
2. **Hack**
    you could set up in your closed network your own "local cdn" that will 
    serve the needed files at the specific domain that it tries to find...
3. **Best but hardest**
   Take and fork graphql-playground and figure out how to not be dependent 
   on the cdn. Then create a pull request that allows the middlewares to be 
   cdn independent

Comment: I ended up going Quick and Hack, grabbing the HTML it generated and grabbing the JavaScript files from the CDN and serving them locally. I hate that answer though, and may try the electron version. While I was looking at the code for options, it seems forking wouldn't be too bad, since it could simply be an update the the Options which are passed in. We'll see if I get more time to work on this.

Comment: There are 2 PRs related, but still no solution, almost a year now :-(
https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground/issues/302 
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1421

Comment: This comment describes a recent workaround: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1421#issuecomment-491249788